# ReferenceError: window is not defined. I got this error when I run npm test to unit testing by jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jestjs

ReferenceError: window is not defined. I got this error when I run npm test to unit testing by jest. Error come from following code export function. Any one met this type of error and solved it?

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from '../modules/rootReducer';

    export function injectAsyncReducers(asyncReducers) {
  const injectReducers = Object.keys(asyncReducers).reduce((all, item) => {
    if (store.asyncReducers[item]) {
      delete all[item];
    }

    return all;
  }, asyncReducers);

  store.asyncReducers = Object.assign({}, store.asyncReducers, injectReducers);
  replaceReducers(rootReducer);
}
```

Comment: The `redux` code in itself has no references to `window`. What does your `rootReducer` look like?

Comment: This is my rootReducer file code import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import menu from '../reducers/fetchMenu';
import orderType from '../reducers/chooseOrderType';
import vendor from '../reducers/fetchVendorInfo';

export default combineReducers({
  menu,
  vendor,
  orderType
});

Answer (score 7):

This error usually comes out when you aren't using the right testEnviremoent configuration for jest, ins this case it should be **jsdom** (you can take a look at it here: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). You can configure it in your *package.json* file like this:

`"jest": {"testEnvironment": "node"}`

If you're using *create-react-app* you test script should be like this:

`"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom"`

Or you can see more options for the testEviroment config here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string

Comment: Adding `--env=jsdom` fixed my issue. I was migrating a project over to CRA and forgot to add that to my test command

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is no window, because you run jest on terminal, not browser. You should define window as a global variable manually.

`package.json`

```
...
"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "window": {
        // whatever you need, put here manually.
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It return the following error typeError: window.WebSocket is not a constructor

Comment: as @henrik-andersson mentioned, you better find the package which references to  `window.WebSocket` .